# How to add an interactive line chart by hovering over barlines

Tags: javascript, css, json, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to visualize an interactive line chart with d3.js. I get the data from a JSON file (dashboard.json). I already have an interactive barchart, which shows a piechart by hovering over the barlines. I'm trying to add a line chart to the barchart. So eventually the hover-over-the-barchart must show both a pie chart and a line chart.

[This is a picture of how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igVDB.png)

Here's my code (some things are in dutch):

```
//barchart
var valueWeek= 36;

var margin = {top: 5, right: 100, bottom: 90, left: 39};
var height = 405;
var barWidth = 50;

var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var output = document.getElementsByTagName('output')[0];
var width = 350;
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0);

//piechart 
var withdPie = 1000;
var heightPie = 1000;
var radiusPie = 160;
var kleur = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#b8d622", "#8523db", "#207cca","#3d1cb2", "#638e00", "#00a000"]);

d3.json('dashboard.json', draw);
function draw(error, data) {
if (error) throw error;


// buttons
d3.select('#week36')
    .on('click', function(){
    week36(); });

function week36(){
    valueWeek = 36;
    console.log(valueWeek);
d3.selectAll(".PieChartBlock").remove(); // RESET PIECHART
d3.selectAll("rect").remove(); // RESET BARCHART
updateBarChart();
}       


 d3.select('#week37')
    .on('click', function(){
    week37(); });

 function week37(){
    valueWeek = 37;
    console.log(valueWeek);
   d3.selectAll(".PieChartBlock").remove(); // RESET PIECHART
    d3.selectAll("rect").remove(); // RESET BARCHART
updateBarChart();
}    


 d3.select('#week38')
    .on('click', function(){
    week38(); });

  function week38(){
    valueWeek = 38;
    console.log(valueWeek);
  d3.selectAll(".PieChartBlock").remove(); // RESET PIECHART
 d3.selectAll("rect").remove(); // RESET BARCHART
updateBarChart();
}


  d3.select('#week39')
    .on('click', function(){
    week39();});

  function week39(){
    valueWeek = 39;
    console.log(valueWeek);
d3.selectAll(".PieChartBlock").remove(); // RESET PIECHART
d3.selectAll("rect").remove(); // RESET BARCHART
updateBarChart();
}


  d3.select('#week40')
    .on('click', function(){
    week40();});

 function week40(){
    valueWeek = 40;
    console.log(valueWeek);
d3.selectAll(".PieChartBlock").remove(); // RESET PIECHART
d3.selectAll("rect").remove(); // RESET BARCHART
updateBarChart();
}



   d3.select('#week41')
    .on('click', function(){
    week41();});

 function week41(){
    valueWeek = 41;
    console.log(valueWeek);
d3.selectAll(".PieChartBlock").remove(); // RESET PIECHART
d3.selectAll("rect").remove(); // RESET BARCHART
updateBarChart();
}


   //barchart
    var EmotieBarchart = d3.select('#EmotieBarchart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.dag; }));
    y.domain([0, 10]);


    //Y-as
    EmotieBarchart
       .append('g')
       .attr('class', 'y axis')
       .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left')); 


      //X-as
   EmotieBarchart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'))
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(40)")
  .attr("dx", "3em")
  .attr("dy", "1em");


   updateBarChart();

 input.addEventListener('input', function () {
d3.selectAll(".PieChartBlock").remove(); // RESET PIECHART
output.value = input.value;
  console.log(" slider update")
updateBarChart();
});


  //update barchart
   function updateBarChart() {
var min = Number(input.value);
var selectedWeek = valueWeek;
var subset = data.filter(function (d) {
return d.gemoed >= min  && d.week == selectedWeek;
});


   var bars = EmotieBarchart.selectAll('.barLine').data(subset);

bars
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr("class", "barLine");

bars
.exit()
.remove();

// Needed to remove all rects before adding one
d3.selectAll('.barLine rect').remove();
d3.selectAll('.barLine text').remove();

bars.append('rect')
    .attr('width', barWidth - 3)
    .attr('x', function (d, i) { return i * barWidth })
    .attr('y', function (d) { return y(d.gemoed); })
    .attr('height', function (d) { return height - y(d.gemoed); })
    .attr('gemoed', function (d) { return d.gemoed })
    .attr('date', function (d) { return d.datum })
    .attr('day', function (d) { return d.dag })
    .attr('number', function (d) { return d.ID })
    .on("mouseover", barMouseOver)
    ;
    }



   // UPDATE PIEBARCHART
   function updatePieChart() {

// PIE CHART
var feest = data[selected].feest;
var boek = data[selected].boek;
var reizen = data[selected].reizen;
var tv = data[selected].tv;
var huishouden = data[selected].huishouden;
var school = data[selected].school;
var dag = data[selected].dag;
var datum = data[selected].datum;
var week = data[selected].week;

//tooltip//
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.style("max-width", "70px")
.style("padding", "1em")
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("z-index", "10")
.style("visibility", "hidden")
.style("background", "white");

//waardes van de piechart
dataPie = [{"label":"TV",         "value":tv}, 
           {"label":"Huishouden", "value":huishouden}, 
           {"label":"Reizen",     "value":reizen},  
           {"label":"school",     "value":school},
           {"label":"boek",       "value":boek},
           {"label":"feest",      "value":feest}];

//piechart visualisatie
var visualchart = d3.select("#DagelijkseActiviteiten")
        .append("svg")              
        .data([dataPie])
        .attr("width", withdPie)
        .attr("height", heightPie)
        .attr("class", "PieChartBlock")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radiusPie*1.5 + "," + radiusPie*1.5 + ")");



// Tekst boven de piechart     
d3.select("#DagelijkseActiviteiten svg")
    .append('text')
    .attr("text-anchor", 'middle')
    .attr("x", "13.5em")
    .attr("y", "2em")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .text(function(d) {
    return 'Dagelijkse activiteiten op ' + dag + ' ' + datum + ' in Week: '+ week;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radiusPie); // Radius

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; }); // Gets value's of school, huishouden and tv

var arcs = visualchart.selectAll("g.slice")     //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
    .data(pie)                          //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties) 
    .enter()                            //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
        .append("g")                //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
        .attr("class", "slice")    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)
        .on("mouseover", function(d){tooltip.text(tv + " uur TV" +' '+ boek + " uur boek"+' '+ school + " uur school"+' '+ reizen + " uur reizen"+' '+ feest +             " uur feest"+' '+ huishouden + " uur huishouden"); return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
        .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-100)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX-25)+"px");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
});


    arcs
    .append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return kleur(i); } )
        .attr("d", arc);

    arcs
    .append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            d.innerRadius = 10;
            d.outerRadius = radiusPie;
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr('class', 'labelText')
        .attr("value", function(d, i) { return dataPie[i].value; })
    .text(function(d, i) { 
        if (dataPie[i].value > 0) { // Checks if value is 0, then is not visible
            return dataPie[i].label; 
        }
    }); 

    }

// Show PieChart that belongs to the bar
function barMouseOver() {
    d3.selectAll(".PieChartBlock").remove();
    selected = d3.select(this).attr("number");
    updatePieChart();
   }
  }
```

This is a short example of my dashboard.json file:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 0,
        "datum": "05-09-2016",
        "week": 36,
        "dag": "maandag",
        "gemoed": 5,
        "school": 3.20,
        "huishouden": 0,
        "tv": 0,
        "reizen": 2.5,
        "feest": 0,
        "boek": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "datum": "06-09-2016",
        "week": 36,
        "dag": "dinsdag",
        "gemoed": 6,
        "school": 0,
        "huishouden": 1,
        "tv": 1,
        "reizen": 0,
        "feest": 0,
        "boek": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "datum": "07-09-2016",
        "week": 36,
        "dag": "woensdag",
        "gemoed": 6,
        "school": 3.50,
        "huishouden": 0,
        "tv": 1,
        "reizen": 3,
        "feest": 0,
        "boek": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "datum": "08-09-2016",
        "week": 36,
        "dag": "donderdag",
        "gemoed": 5,
        "school": 6.40,
        "huishouden": 0,
        "tv": 0,
        "reizen": 2.10,
        "feest": 0,
        "boek": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": 4,
        "datum": "09-09-2016",
        "week": 36,
        "dag": "vrijdag",
        "gemoed": 7,
        "school": 0,
        "huishouden": 1,
        "tv": 4,
        "reizen": 0,
        "feest": 0,
        "boek": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": 5,
        "datum": "10-09-2016",
        "week": 36,
        "dag": "zaterdag",
        "gemoed": 9,
        "school": 0,
        "huishouden": 0,
        "tv": 0,
        "reizen": 0,
        "feest": 12,
        "boek": 0
    },
    {
        "ID": 6,
        "datum": "11-09-2016",
        "week": 36,
        "dag": "zondag",
        "gemoed": 7,
        "school": 0,
        "huishouden": 0,
        "tv": 4,
        "reizen": 0,
        "feest": 0,
        "boek": 1
    }]
```

Comment: Can you make a working example?

Comment: This code only seems to run via mac's terminal. I can't view it offline. How can I make a working example for you to show?

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k57yzxgj/ this is what I get. Still not showing everything

Comment: You should add d3 as an external resource. Look for it here: https://cdnjs.com/

Comment: I still can't make it work... I know i'm such a noob

Comment: Take a look in the browser's developer tool console for any errors. This will give you a hint as to what might be missing to complete your example.

Comment: This is what is says: d3.min.js:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file: dashboard.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: As said ksav. Import d3.min.js file from cdnjs.com. you imported the js from another source and this source not allow to call js file from another web page. And if you can please add complete html code to your question

Comment: am I supposed to paste this: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.7/d3.min.js"></script> to my html file? If so, it is still not working.

Comment: Is this the only way? I changed my d3.min.js file for another one but it breaks my code somehow. I really need help

Comment: I added a picture of what it looks like when I run the code via my terminal